# How to convert RGB to CIELAB or L* a* b* on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have RGB value `rgb[253, 216, 28]` but i want to convert it to CIELAB or L*,a*,b* value in flutter how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package: `flutter_color_model`. Link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_color_models

So we will create a function to convert from RGB to CIELAB for convenient:

```
List<double> fromRGBtoCIELAB(int red, int green, int blue){
  Color color = Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, 1);
  LabColor labColor = LabColor.fromColor(color);
  return [
    double.parse(labColor.lightness.toString()),
    double.parse(labColor.a.toString()),
    double.parse(labColor.b.toString()),
  ];
}
```

Remember to add `flutter_color_model` to your `pubspec.yaml` file and `import 'package:flutter_color_models/flutter_color_models.dart';` in your code ;)